# unresolved requiremnet: Import-package : com.google.api.client.auth.client.auth.oauth2; version={1.30.0,2.0.0}

Tags: gradle, liferay

liferay 7.2 version

tomcat-9.0.17

gradle.build

```
compileOnly group: "com.google.api-client", name: "google-api-client", version: ':1.23.0'

compileOnly group: "com.google.oauth-client", name: "google-oauth-client-jetty", version: "1.23.0"

compileOnly group: "com.google.apis", name: "google-api-services-drive", version: "v3-rev110-1.23.0"
```

i need use java upload file to google drive

when i start server, i hit this error

[![Liferay console output showing error message][1]][1]

```
2020-06-23 11:10:58.525 INFO  [main][PortalContextLoaderListener:139] JVM arguments: -Dcatalina.base=C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.17 -Dcatalina.home=C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.17 -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.17/endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.17/temp -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2/tomcat-9.0.17/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx2560m
2020-06-23 11:11:04.476 INFO  [main][DialectDetector:159] Using dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect for MySQL 8.0
2020-06-23 11:11:08.647 INFO  [main][ModuleFrameworkImpl:1468] Starting initial bundles
2020-06-23 11:11:08.694 ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 6c1b290f-406b-44be-9cec-6423b761abd2][Framework:93] FrameworkEvent ERROR 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: hero [2129]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2; version="[1.23.0,2.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1662)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:115)
    at com.liferay.portal.bootstrap.ModuleFrameworkImpl.startFramework(ModuleFrameworkImpl.java:399)
    at com.liferay.portal.module.framework.ModuleFrameworkUtilAdapter.startFramework(ModuleFrameworkUtilAdapter.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
```

i refer this link https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

any know how to solve ?

Comment: Kindly explain your problem in more details and provide the community with a little more overview of it.

Comment: ...and please don't post textual content as image (edit your question, replacing the image with text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compileOnly` will make your dependencies available at compile time *only*. You will need to make sure that they're available at runtime as well (together with all the required transitive dependencies).

Ideally, if all required dependencies are already OSGi bundles, you just drop them in Liferay's `deploy` folder and deploy them to the runtime - and they'll automagically be available.

If your dependencies aren't OSGi bundles: Check if you find a fork of these dependencies which differs only by adding required OSGi directives in the manifest. Or, as a last resort, really not recommended, you can use `compileInclude`. This will package the dependencies with your plugin, at the cost of a larger plugin and potential clashes if you do this in multiple of your plugins and expect them all to handle the same data: You won't be able to pass these objects around.

I have a chapter on exactly this topic in a (free, registration required) course [OSGi Basics](https://university.liferay.com/osgi-basics/356174), over on Liferay University. But the main information is what you see above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding your dependencies to the folder {LIFERAY_HOME}/tomcat-XX/lib/ext? With your *compileOnly* you're telling gradle that the dependencies will be present in runtime.

Comment: `tomcat/lib/ext` won't help to resolve any OSGi dependency. Deploying the dependencies (as OSGi Bundles) to the runtime will.